# help with php AND condition

Tags: php

Need help reworking this php code/logic. Right now, if I have no value for either column 'Duration' or 'Size', my html table is blank and I put a default value of `n/a`.

I want to change the logic to continue to handle that condition and give an `n/a` value, but also add the logic to read if BOTH are `n/a`, then set my column 'Status' value = 'In Progress'.

Somehow, my commented code isn't working right. Thanks.

```
     foreach ($keys as $column){
        if (isset($row[$column])){
                if ($column == 'Server'){
                        echo '<td> <a href="' . $server_array[$row[$column]] . '">' . $row[$column] . '</a></td>';
                } elseif ($column == 'Status'){  
                        echo '<td> <font color="' . $color_array[$row[$column]] . '">' . $row[$column] . '</font></td>';
                } else {
                        echo '<td>' . $row[$column] . '</td>';
                }
        } elseif ($column == 'Status') {
          echo '<td><font color="yellow"> Review </font></td>';
        } elseif ($column == 'Duration') {
          echo '<td> n/a </td>';
        } elseif ($column == 'Size') {
          echo '<td> n/a </td>';
        //} elseif ($column == 'Duration') && ($column =='Size') {
        // echo '<td> In Progress </td>';
        } else {
          echo '<td> </td>';
        }
     }
```

Comment: `} elseif ($column == 'Duration') && ($column =='Size') {`  <-- This will never work because `$column` can't have two values at the same time.

Comment: I'm not sure how `$column == 'Duration'` would determine weather or not the column called 'Duration' has a value or not, I think you need to restate your problem, and post some of the other code so we can see the context.

Comment: i added the other code to get a better understanding of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
} elseif ($column == 'Status') {
  if (!isset($row['Duration']) && !isset($row['Size']))
    echo '<td> In Progress </td>';
  else
    echo '<td><font color="yellow"> Review </font></td>';
}
```

instead of

```
} elseif ($column == 'Status') {
  echo '<td><font color="yellow"> Review </font></td>';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
switch ($column){
  case "Status":
   $html="<font color="yellow"> Review </font>";
   break;
  case "Duration":
  case "Size":
   $html="n/a";
   break;
  case "SOME_OTHER_SOMETHING":
   $html=" In Progress ";
   break;
  default:
   $html="";
   break;
```

}

`echo"<td>$html</td>";`

Comment: you don't want to get into heavliy shelled if statements when a switch statement is easier to use....

Answer (score 0):

The commented out code should be:

```
} elseif (($column != 'Duration') && ($column != 'Size')) {
    echo '<td> In Progress </td>';
```

...assuming you want it to say `In Progress` when `column` is not `Duration` or `Size`.

Note that with this logic, the last `else` will never be reached, so it can just be removed.

Also, the question could be made clearer, as I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

You need to either drop a few parens or add a few, so that `($column == 'Duration') && ($column =='Size')` becomes `(($column == 'Duration') && ($column =='Size'))` or `($column == 'Duration' && $column =='Size')`

But you have a bigger problem see  R. Bemrose's comment on your question.

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for something with an or. Like  column = 'blah' or column = 'blah2'.

```
else if ($column == 'Duration' || $column =='Size')
```